# pandas compare two dataframes and creating 0 columns

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
df1

Year    Column1   Column2   Column3
2022    1          2         3
2022    5          7         9


df2

Year    Column1    Column4    Column5
2022     1          2          4
```

What I want to achieve is that in df2, I want to detect the missing columns (in this case it would be `Column2` and `Column3` and fill `0`)
So my `df2` would ultimately look like:

```
df2

Year     Column1   Column4   Column5   Column2   Column3
2022      1         2         4         0         0
```

How do I achieve this? I tried `map` but wasnt able to get it to work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the columns in df1, check if they are in df2 and, if they are not, add them in like this:

```py
for col in df1.columns:
    if col not in df2.columns:
        df2[col] = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and column [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
out = df2.reindex(df2.columns.union(df1.columns), axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

To update in place:

```
df2.update(df2.reindex(df2.columns.union(df1.columns), axis=1, fill_value=0))
```

Comment: Have you tested this approach? This should be more efficient than a double loop